# Set phone to unlock when pressing fingerprint sensor button (LG V20)

Tags: lock-screens, lg

I'm not sure if the above question is specific to the device, the LG version of Android, or a general Android limitation/issue, so apologies if my tags are inaccurate.

---

LG V20 user here, running Android 7.0, the latest update for the device so far.

Phone is set to unlock using fingerprints, with the fingerprint sensor slash button on the backside of the device.

Currently, the phone unlocks both when I *press* this button or when I simply *rest* one of the registered fingers on the sensor, leading to 'accidental' unlocks sometimes, e.g. when simply picking up the phone.

**My question:** Is it possible to change this behavior (In stock Android? In some custom ROM?) to only unlock when the fingerprint sensor button is actively *pressed*, not when a finger simply rests on the sensor?